# Resampling a time series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, max, resampling

I have a 40 year time series in the format stn;yyyymmddhh;rainfall , where yyyy= year, mm = month, dd= day,hh= hour.  The series is at an hourly resolution. I extracted the maximum values for each year by the following groupby method:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('data.txt', delimiter = ";")
df['yyyy'] = df['yyyymmhhdd'].astype(str).str[:4]
df.groupby(['yyyy'])['rainfall'].max().reset_index()
```

Now, i am trying to extract the maximum values for 3 hour duration each year. I tried this sliding maxima approach but it is not working. k is the duration I am interested in. In simple words,i need maximum precipitation sum for multiple durations in every year (eg 3h, 6h, etc)

```
class AMS:
    def sliding_max(self, k, data):
        tp = data.values
        period = 24*365
        agg_values = []
        start_j = 1
        end_j = k*int(np.floor(period/k))
        for j in range(start_j, end_j + 1):
            start_i = j - 1
            end_i = j + k + 1
            agg_values.append(np.nansum(tp[start_i:end_i]))
        self.sliding_max = max(agg_values)
        return self.sliding_max
```

Any suggestions or improvements in my code or is there a way i can implement it with groupby. I am a bit new to python environment, so please excuse if the question isn't put properly.

```
Stn;yyyymmddhh;rainfall 
xyz;1981010100;0.0
xyz;1981010101;0.0
xyz;1981010102;0.0
xyz;1981010103;0.0
xyz;1981010104;0.0
xyz;1981010105;0.0
xyz;1981010106;0.0
xyz;1981010107;0.0
xyz;1981010108;0.0
xyz;1981010109;0.4
xyz;1981010110;0.6
xyz;1981010111;0.1
xyz;1981010112;0.1
xyz;1981010113;0.0
xyz;1981010114;0.1
xyz;1981010115;0.6
xyz;1981010116;0.0
xyz;1981010117;0.0
xyz;1981010118;0.2
xyz;1981010119;0.0
xyz;1981010120;0.0
xyz;1981010121;0.0
xyz;1981010122;0.0
xyz;1981010123;0.0
xyz;1981010200;0.0
```

Comment: Pandas already has a `resample` function for time series data: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html Is your question about getting the resampling done (I would prefer using pandas) or about your own implementation?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As i mentioned, i am open to suggestions. My own implementation seems to not work. I was checking the resampling function of pandas but i am getting confused with the date-time indexing there

Answer (score 1):

You first have to convert your column containing the datetimes to a `Series` of type `datetime`. You can do that parsing by providing the format of your datetimes.

```
df["yyyymmddhh"] = pd.to_datetime(df["yyyymmddhh"], format="%Y%M%d%H")
```

After having the correct data type you have to set that column as your index and can now use `pandas` functionality for time series data (resampling in your case).
First you resample the data to 3 hour windows and sum the values. From that you resample to yearly data and take the maximum value of all the 3 hour windows for each year.

```
df.set_index("yyyymmddhh").resample("3H").sum().resample("Y").max()

# Output
yyyymmddhh  rainfall 
1981-12-31  1.1
```

Comment: Many thanks for the reply. It worked, but i am wondering about the values which look a bit weird like for example 1981-12-31 STnStnStn 8.01.13.1

Comment: Can you please provide a part of your Dataframe?

Comment: Sample is added now

Comment: I edited the function based on your changed column naming. Is that the desired output? I don't get the weird example you provided.

Comment: This is exactly the desired output. But, i am not getting it, despite using the exact same functions.I am getting the output in the form of 3 columns   yyyymmddhh Stn rainfall                                                                                                          1980-12-31 NaN      NaN

Comment: I think there might be missing data in the 40 year series because i am getting a column of NaN

Comment: How do I give a time interval to the above function like lets say from 1981-2000. I tried df['1981-12-31': '2000-12-31'] but it returned error messages